# Search for a directory and delete it

Tags: windows, script

I want to search the c: drive for the existence of directory called XYZ. Then I want to delete it and all of it's contents. There will be multiple directories named XYZ at different levels in the directory tree. I want to delete them all. This needs to be done on a windows system. I can run UNIX commands using cygwin if required. Any help in achieving this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test these before using them.

**Windows CMD command line**

```
for /f "tokens=*" %G in ('dir /b /s /a:d "XYZ"') do rmdir /s /q "%G"
```

**Windows CMD script**

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /s /a:d "XYZ"') do rmdir /s /q "%%G"
```

**bash/cygwin**

```
find . -name 'XYZ' -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: I tested the last one, and while it works, it gave an error, saying that it could not find the parent directory.  I don't know why this happens, so if somebody does, that would be cool.

Comment: For the Windows-based examples, I would change the `del /s /q "%%g"` line to `rd /s /q "%%g"` so that the entire folder is deleted, including the folder you were looking for. Don't forget to enclose it in quotes in case there are spaces in the path.

Comment: @JSanchez: Yes, you are totally right.  I forgot to do that in my haste to answer first.  Edited.